# realloc Corrupting Source Memory

Tags: c, malloc

I'm attempting to understand why realloc appears to be corrupting the source block of memory that I'm expanding. I've not ruled out the possibility that something in my code is incorrect. The code is using constructs from C SFML.

```
sfUint16* num_frames = malloc (sizeof (sfUint16)); if (NULL == num_frames) exit (-1);
(*num_frames) = 10;
printf ("num_frames address: %p\n", num_frames);
printf ("num_frames value: %i\n", (*num_frames));

sfIntRect* base_frames = malloc ((*num_frames) * sizeof (sfIntRect)); if (NULL == base_frames) exit (-1);
printf ("base_frames address: %p\n", base_frames);
for (int a = 0; a < (*num_frames); a++) {
    base_frames [a].top = 10;
    base_frames [a].left = 10;
    base_frames [a].width = 50;
    base_frames [a].height = 100;
    printf ("base_frames allocation %i: %i, %i, %i, %i\n", a, base_frames [a].top, base_frames [a].left, base_frames [a].width, base_frames [a].height);
}

sfIntRect* sample_frame = malloc (sizeof (sfIntRect)); if (NULL == sample_frame) exit (-1);
sample_frame->top = 20;
sample_frame->left = 20;
sample_frame->width = 200;
sample_frame->height = 300;
printf ("sample_frame address: %p\n", sample_frame);
printf ("base_frames[5] preassignment: %i, %i, %i, %i\n", base_frames [5].top, base_frames [5].left, base_frames [5].width, base_frames [5].height);
base_frames [5] = (*sample_frame);
printf ("base_frames[5] postassignment: %i, %i, %i, %i\n", base_frames [5].top, base_frames [5].left, base_frames [5].width, base_frames [5].height);
free (sample_frame);
printf ("base_frames[5] postfree of sample_frame: %i, %i, %i, %i\n", base_frames [5].top, base_frames [5].left, base_frames [5].width, base_frames [5].height);

sfIntRect* new_frames = realloc (base_frames, (*num_frames) * 2);
if (new_frames) base_frames = new_frames;
else free (new_frames);
printf ("address of base_frames: %p\n", base_frames);
for (int a = 0; a < (*num_frames) * 2; a++) {
    printf ("base_frames allocation %i: %i, %i, %i, %i\n", a, base_frames [a].top, base_frames [a].left, base_frames [a].width, base_frames [a].height);
}

free (num_frames);
free (base_frames);

return 0;
```

The compiler output looks like this (obviously, memory addresses change per run):

[Program Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X76FU.png)

Info: sfIntRect is four integer values consolidated.

What I've noticed here is that from everything I've read on realloc, it appears to work in that new_frames returns the same original address as base_frames, and the size of the block has increased. The additions to the block aren't initialized, so I expect the values of those constructs to be wacky, which they are. However, the first ten allocations shouldn't be compromised and it looks as if two of them are. This happens every run with the same elements.

Can someone help shed some light on this?

Comment: You need to check return from realloc

Comment: Unrelated, but (1) why malloc a sungle integer, or a single sample frame? (2) `else free (new_frames)` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @n.m. Point 2 was addressed below. Point 1 is simply because I'm playing with the code, no more, no less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute the

```
... = realloc(... , (*num_frames) * 2);
```

for:

```
... = realloc(..., (*num_frames) * 2 * sizeof(sfIntRect));
```

You don't want to allocate `(*num_frames) * 2` bytes, but want to allocate `(*num_frames) * 2` "frames", with one frames having `sizoef(sfIntRect)` bytes. The memory you access in the following `printf` is invalid if realloc succedeed,  assuming `sizeof(sfIntRect) > 1`.

The `else free (new_frames);` after `if (new_frames)` looks pointless, you already now, that `new_frames == NULL` no point in free-ing it.

I think I have to subjectively to mark that spaces after function call, ex. `printf (...)`. `free (...)`, `realloc (..)`, and spaces before using `[]` operator look unreadable to me. Also lines that long are unreadable. I prefer using the syntax where spaces are only used after conditional constructs `if` `while` `for` and the function calls have spaces only after `,` separating arguments.

Comment: The immediate issue has been corrected. I didn't even notice that I hadn't included the sizeof in the realloc. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The check after realloc was a pattern I'd seen about addressing the return of realloc. In hindsight, there are probably more effective ways of asserting this. Back to the drawing board. Insofar as syntax style goes, while I'm not a huge fan of long lines myself, this is disposable code ergo I'm not concerned about it, although I apologize for not chopping it down for SO. Spaces after function calls and arrays are easier for me to read personally. Thanks for the help!